# Getting numbers from a string in iPhone programming

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a string. It's always 3 letters long, and it can be counted on to only contain three integers. Say it looks like this:

```
NSString * numberString = @"123";
```

Now, I want to extract those numbers from it. 1, 2 and 3. In any other language I'd just fetch the character for each position and parse it, or even cast it.

However, Objective-C doesn't seem to have that. I found some other answer recommending that i use the `characterAtIndex` method, use `numberWithChar` on that, and then subtract the number "48" from it, leaving even myself scratching my head at the apparent stupidity of it all.

Is there no other, more elegant way to do this?

I tried using substringWithRange, but apparently there's no method for creating an NSRange, and it's incompatible with CFRangeMake for some reason.

Comment: They're recommending subtracting 48, which is 0x30 in hex, because that's the ASCII value of the character '0'. The character '1' is 0x31 (49), so on and so forth, so 49-48 == 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about [[numberString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,1)] intValue]?

Comment: There's the one i was looking for - guess i wasn't trying hard enough to find the `NSMakeRange()` method. Will be marking as answer when it's possible.

Comment: This method is great for parsing numbers of more than one digit, but for one digit numbers it creates an unnecessary NSString object and whatever overhead intValue may have.

Answer (score 1):

```
int n=[@"123" intValue];
```

From this you can get the individual numbers by n/100, n/10 and n%10.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
NSString * numberString = @"123";
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
NSNumber *number = [formatter numberFromString:numberString];
int n = [number intValue];
```

(Don't forget to release the formatter after you finish your conversions.)

Comment: FYI, you can just do `int n = [numberString intValue]` and skip the numberFormatter.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *numberString = @"123";
int firstDigit  = [numberString characterAtIndex:0] - '0';
int secondDigit = [numberString characterAtIndex:1] - '0';
int thirdDigit  = [numberString characterAtIndex:2] - '0';
NSLog(@"Your digits are %d, %d, %d", firstDigit, secondDigit, thirdDigit);
```

If you want to cheat:

```
char *numberString = [@"123" cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
printf(@"Your digits are %d, %d, %d\n", numberString[0] - '0',
                                        numberString[1] - '0',
                                        numberString[2] - '0');
```